# Creating an instance of a class with parameters

Tags: swift

In a swift lesson I'm going through it says this is a valid way of creating an instance of a class:

```
class Heroes
{
    var (name, gender, kingdom) = ("","","")
    var (level, ad, hp) = (0,0,0)

    init(name: String)
    {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

The part below is what is causing this error *`"cannot assign value of type '(name: String)' to type 'Heroes'`*

```
let sirGeorge: Heroes
sirGeorge = (name: "Sir George")
```

The below way works fine but I don't understand the syntax of the way above, nor does the compiler. Is there a new way in Swift 3 of writing this perhaps?

```
var sirLance = Heroes(name: "Sir Lancelot")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you want to create the object Heroes, first you need to use the Class Name **Heroes** then the parenthesis with its arguments **(name: "Sir George")**, like so:

```
let sirGeorge: Heroes
sirGeorge = Heroes(name: "Sir George")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sirGeorge: Heroes
```

You create constant with `let` and name `sirGeorge` and you set that type of the constant is `Heroes`. It is value reference data type.

```
sirGeorge = (name: "Sir George")
```

Second line you try to assign to constant with type `Heroes` new value that content type `'(name: String)'` and hear you receive issue. Because you're type is `Heroes` and not `'(name: String)'`. In another hand you try to assign to value constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this 
sirGeorge = (name: "Sir George")
is like you want to assign  (name: "Sir George") to sirGeorge  which is wrong because sirGeorge  is an object of class Heroes

So this is the right way

sirGeorge = Heroes(name: "Sir George")

because now you are initialising your object. It is like calling init(lets say init function ) and init takes a String "Sir George"

Answer (score 0):

**Line 1:** `let sirGeorge: Heroes`

Here you are creating a constant `sirGeorge` of type `Heroes`. This is correct. The only value `sirGeorge` can take must be of type `Heroes` and nothing else.

**Line 2:** `sirGeorge = (name: "Sir George")`

Here you are assigning `sirGeorge` a value  that is of type `(name: "Sir George")` and not `Heroes`. So in order to assign value to `sirGeorge` you need to create an instance of `Heroes` ,i.e,

```
sirGeorge = Heroes(name: "Sir George")
```

This will call the `init(name: String`) of `Heroes`.